# Android SDK public void gets an error

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a problem by following a tutorial for making an app. But now I get an error by adding an respond
for a button. It gives an error at public void sendMessage, but I cant see what is wrong.

```
 package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.Intent;




/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */

public void sendMessage(View view){

Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
}


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant portion of your logCat

Comment: You defined a method before even class ???? Strange.

Answer (score 3):

those lines

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */

public void sendMessage(View view){ 
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
}
```

go into your class, after

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is outside the activity.

Move

```
public void sendMessage(View view){

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
}
```

inside Activity like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    //other code i.e. onCreate etc

    public void sendMessage(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    }

}
```